# Get COM/DCOM Connections?

Tags: c++, dcom, opc

I'd like to figure out what IP address a DCOM client is connecting from. I have an OPC server,  and from the context of the COM/DCOM code, there is no way to get the client IP that I can find. This article appears to confirm that (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sanpil/archive/2004/03/01/82302.aspx).

I tried using a C++ library that netstat uses (iphlpapi.lib, GetExtendedTcpTable) to get open connections with no luck. It looks like COM/DCOM defaults to UDP.

The only other thing I can think of is using WireShark pcap to try and capture inbound traffic on port 135?

Does anyone have any clever ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's said "Using DCOM through firewalls becomes problematic because it dynamically allocates one port per process (configurable through the registry) and requires UPD and TCP ports 135-139 to be open. ".

Comment: Yeah, the problem is I don't believe you can associate the port with a specific process. It's all buried in the windows 'stuff'. I can look into this though. Currently I've only been testing with COM (local) which may be using a different technique. If this is the case then the only thing I can do (I think) is sniff the traffic on a range of ports, and try to figure it out based on the content of the messages. Seems like a lot of work...

Comment: So I can't match it to the process ID, but this is good enough for my needs. I look for out/inbound TCP/IP connections on port 135 and report on the remote IP address. It means I can't get the IP 100% of the time (return multiple if there is more than one DCOM connection, and none if it's a local connection OR using UDP), but this is good enough for my app.